# How can I add extra textarea fields to a form

Tags: python, django

I need to generate several textareas to be filled by users and submitted back to the model. However, I think they need all to have different names (am i correct?)

How can I generate random names for each textarea and how can the model get the data within one it gets the POST request?

Thanks!

EDIT: I was hoping to use the randomly generated name as a way to identify the content and to save them in the database

Comment: Why do they need to be random? Why not, for example, sequential?

Comment: it is random because multiple user could create these textarea and so sequential could cause problem when saving

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to give you a good answer here because you haven't indicated what you're actually trying to achieve. You could add a 1000 text fields to your form, but if they don't correlate somehow to data on your model, there's not much point, and you've neglected that crucial piece of information.

Still, on a very basic level, you can add the additional textareas to your form like so:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for i in range(1, 11):
            self.fields['mytextarea%d' % i] = forms.CharField(label='Textarea %d' % i, widget=forms.Textarea)
```

**UPDATE**

Based on your comment, and the fact that you're intending to actually store and retrieve the textarea fields at a later point, you should create a separate model for them and link it to your main model through a one-to-many relationship. For example:

```
class PrimaryModel(models.Model):
    ... # Stuff here

class TextareaModel(models.Model):
    myprimarymodel = models.ForeignKey(PrimaryModel)
    mytextarea = models.TextField()
```

It's hard to give a good example since you haven't indicated anything about what your models look like, but the basic idea is that you have a model that contains nothing but a foreign key to the main model and a textarea field. You can then treat these textareas as inlines with via a model formset.

Comment: these textareas are a way to add stuff into the database. A user could potentially generate 1000 textarea, fill them with something and then submit them to be saved. Later he/she could retrieve these 1000 textarea